# `numpy.empty()` and `numpy.random.rand()` same or different

Tags: python, function, numpy, random

In `NumPy` there are two functions, one is `numpy.random.rand()` and another is `numpy.empty()`. Both functions are giving me same output.
Code:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand(3,2)
array([[0.54372255, 0.68730993],
       [0.97759727, 0.39876009],
       [0.47325882, 0.57949219]])

>>> np.empty([3,2])
array([[0.54372255, 0.68730993],
       [0.97759727, 0.39876009],
       [0.47325882, 0.57949219]])
```

Because both of them are giving the same output, both are the same or different?
here I mean with same that both functions have similar implementations or they have different implementations

If both are different then which one is better or efficient?

Comment: Read their documentation to see, that those do not have anything in common.  Maybe also google *uninitialized memory (or wikis [Uninitialized variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable))*.

Comment: They are not the same, try using both functions in reverse order. `numpy` uses memory available from your previous initialization to claim memory for `np.empty()`, because it is a block of memory with an appropriate size.

Comment: Oh, i understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different!

Rand,  based on a seed **generate** some numbers of a given shape.

On the other part, **empty** return an **unitializated** array, so it means that is pointing to a random memory location, accidentally this return random values, but out of control, in your example gc has released the memoty location so the same area was occupied by empty with the same shape.

So don't use empty for generate random values